# Проблема с асинхронным запросом jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax

такая проблема. Пишу умный поиск по сайту, при нажатии на кнопку отправляю запрос на выборку из бд.
К примеру ввожу слово "стол", уходит запрос по слову "сто", далее я ввожу букву "л" и уходит запрос со словом "стол".
После чего запрос со словом "стол" приходит быстрее, а уже после него приходит ответ запроса "сто" и соответственно перекрывает нужный мне ответ. Есть какие то выходы?
вот код

```
$(document).on('keyup', '#fastcat', function () {

    var ad = $(this);
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "/ajax/fastcat?q=" + ad.val(),
        beforeSend: function () {
            if (ad.val().length > 1) {
                $(".fastcat_auto").removeClass('visible');
                $('.fastcat_div .loader').show();
            }

        },
        success: function (html) {
            $('.fastcat_div .loader').hide();
            if (html != 'fail') {
                $('.fastcat_auto').html('');
                $('.fastcat_auto').html(html);
                $(".fastcat_auto").addClass('visible');
            } else {
                if (ad.val().length > 1) {
                    $('.fastcat_auto').html('<ul><li>Ничего не найдено.</li> </ul>');
                    $(".fastcat_auto").addClass('visible');
                }

            }
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Увы, жизнь не дала нам экстрасенсорных способностей. Можете показать код?

Comment: да, только если вы скажете  как в комментах его писать. В вопросе есть "код", а в коментах так и не разобрался

Comment: вставьте в сообщение, выделите код и нажмите на картинку {}

Comment: поправил вопрос

Comment: код вроде бы в порядке, можете показать страницу на которой тестируете это? и ещё, возможно php съедает символ? попробуйте вывести в php-файле `print_r($_GET);`

Comment: @ikerya, обычная гонка колбэков, при быстрой посылке запросов, никто не гарантирует, что ответы придут в том же порядке, что были посланы

Comment: в том то и дело что если печатать медленно по одному символу то все ок, а если быстро, то как лотерея. Может нормально сработает а может и нет...

Comment: да, не заметил новое изменение

Comment: Как вариант, можно просто делать задержку перед посылкой запроса, чтобы слать не на каждой нажатие кнопки

Comment: тоже такая мысль возникла но как сделать задержку?

Comment: например через `setTimeout`, и в обработчике очищать таймер, и запускать новый, соответственно пока подряд идет нажатие будет откладываться посылка, а когда промежуток будет побольше пошлется

Comment: @Анатолий попробуйте отправлять запрос только по нажатию на Enter

Comment: @Grundy понравился твой вариант но попробовал так, не выходит

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Все просто. При получении ответа проверяйте что посылали, соответствует ли оно текущему значению input'а.

Псевдокод:

```
function search(){
  var query = $edit.val();
  $.ajax("?search="+query)
    .done(data => if(query!=$edit.val()) return; pupulate(data););
}
```

Comment: Ваш ответ помог. Хотелось бы узнать, где вы получили знания о jquery. Ваш синтаксис отличается от того который знаю я, хотел бы поднатаскать себя.

Comment: @Анатолий все пишут код по своему

Comment: @Анатолий это псевдокод в стиле ecmascript 6 (с ошибками в синтаксисе), главное - идея.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте при вводе символов в текстовом поле через каждые 200 миллисекунд (если нужно, можете быстрее) проверять, совпадает ли время текущего запроса с переменной time_passed (она меняется при вводе символов в текстовое поле).

```
var time_passed = 0;

function sendRequest(ad) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "/ajax/fastcat?q=" + ad.val(),
        beforeSend: function () {
            if (ad.val().length > 1) {
                $(".fastcat_auto").removeClass('visible');
                $('.fastcat_div .loader').show();
            }

        },
        success: function (html) {
            $('.fastcat_div .loader').hide();
            if (html != 'fail') {
                $('.fastcat_auto').html('');
                $('.fastcat_auto').html(html);
                $(".fastcat_auto").addClass('visible');
            } else {
                if (ad.val().length > 1) {
                    $('.fastcat_auto').html('<ul><li>Ничего не найдено.</li> </ul>');
                    $(".fastcat_auto").addClass('visible');
                }

            }
        }
    });
}

$(document).on('keyup', '#fastcat', function (e) {
    var typed_time = new Date().getTime() / 1000;
    time_passed = typed_time;

    setTimeout(function() {
      if(time_passed == typed_time) {
        sendRequest($(e.currentTarget));
      }
    }, 200);
});
```

Comment: тогда вообще пропадает идея быстрого поиска...

Comment: попробуйте ещё раз)

Answer (score 0):

Вариант с откладывание запуска запроса:

```
var filterTimer,
    timeout = 500;
$(document).on('keyup', '#fastcat', function () {
    var ad = $(this);
    clearTimeout(filterTimer);
    filterTimer = setTimeout(function(){
        $.ajax({...});
    }, timeout);
});
```

Данный способ, не решает основную проблему очередности запросов, но позволяет уменьшить возможность ее воспроизведения, за счет снижения количества запросов и увеличения времени между ними.

Альтернативным решением может быть построение очереди запросов, например так:

```
var queue;
$(document).on('keyup', '#fastcat', function () {
    var adVal = $(this).val();
    if(!queue){
        queue = $.ajax({
            ...
            url: "/ajax/fastcat?q=" + adVal,
            beforeSend: function () {
                if (adVal.length > 1) {...}
            }
            ...
        });
    }else{
        queue.done(function(){
            return $.ajax({
                ...
                url: "/ajax/fastcat?q=" + adVal,
                beforeSend: function () {
                    if (adVal.length > 1) {...}
                }
                ...
            });
        });
    }
});
```