# В callback getJSON не могу очистить HTML

Tags: jquery, ajax

Если быстро вводить символы в поле поиска, то 'очистка' `$('.twitch-row').remove();` почему то не происходить и новые результаты поиска наслаиваются на предыдущие. Как помочь?

```
 var searchField = $("#input-search");
searchField.keyup(function(){
        searchText = $(this).val();
        if (searchText.length > 3) {
            searchedChannels = [];
            $.getJSON('https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/search/channels?q='+ searchText +'&limit=7', function(data) {
                searchedChannels = [];
                $('.twitch-row').remove();
                data.channels.forEach(function(item) {
                    searchedChannels.push(item.name);
                });
                searchedChannels.forEach(getData);
            });
        }
});

function getData(item) {
    $.getJSON(createUrl('getStream', item), function(data) {
        var channelData = parseData(data, item);
        createHTMLRow(channelData);
    });
}

function createHTMLRow(data) {
    var cssClass = isChannelOnline(data.status);
    salvattore.appendElements(grid, [item]);
    /*console.log(data)*/
    item.outerHTML = '<a href="'+ data.linkSrc +'" class="twitch-row '+ cssClass +'" target="_blank"><img src="'+ data.imageSrc +'" class="row-img"><div class="channel"><div class="chanel-name">'+ data.channelName +'</div><div class="chanel-decription">'+ data.descriptionChanel +'</div></div></div></a>';
}
```

Comment: а `getData` где?

Comment: getData   добавил ниже

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы на каждое событие `focus` добавляете новый обработчик `keyup`. Очень скоро Вам от этих киапов некуда будет деваться.

```
var searchField = $("#input-search");
searchField.keyup(function(){
  ...
});
```

Продолжаем.

У Вас получилось слишком много асинхронности. Ответы на множество ajax-запросов приходят в произвольном порядке, оттого и данные наслаиваются.

Как советовали недавно в [Проблема с асинхронным запросом jquery](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/538303)

```
searchField.keyup(function(){
  var searchText = $(this).val();
  if (searchText.length > 3) {
    searchedChannels = [];
    $.getJSON('https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/search/channels?q='+ searchText +'&limit=7', function(data) {
      if (searchText != searchField.val())
        return;
      searchedChannels = [];
      $('.twitch-row').remove();
      data.channels.forEach(function(item) {
        searchedChannels.push(item.name);
      });
      searchedChannels.forEach(getData);
    });
  }
});
```

Но и этого может быть недостаточно из-за многочисленных ajax-запросов в `searchedChannels.forEach(getData);`. Рассмотрите возможность получения описаний для всех имен за один запрос.

Comment: Спасибо, поправил, ну суть вопроса все еще не получилось решить.

Comment: Чтобы реализовать живой поиск с пред просмотром результатов, приходиться сначала делать запрос по нажатию с введенными символами, ответ от сервера - варианты полных  имен, но только имена, чтобы получить описания приходиться для каждого имени делать запрос и получать уже данные. Поэтому и столько много запросов получается.

Comment: Спасибо помогло. Проблема решена вашим способом.